# Even after sign with firmware signatures Android app listed under 'Download apps'?

Tags: android, apk, root, pem, android-install-apk

I'm working on an Android app which will be shipped with firmware. I already got .pk8 file and .pem file from firmware provider to sign my apk. I used signapk.jar file to sign the android apk as described [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files/).

When I install the signed apk on the device I noticed that the app still listed under 'Downloaded app' which mean its not considered as system app even after sign using the firmware keys. Also I add these line

> android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"

to Mainfest file and tried, still same.

My ultimate requirement is developing a system app which cannot be uninstalled(or force-stopped) by the end user. I have support from firmware provider. Please share your idea on achieving this?

Comment: you have to place it to the system partition for it to become a *completely system app*

Comment: after signing the apk I just installed like a regular app. how to place it to the system partition?

Comment: system apps are placed in `system/app/<app_name>/<app_name>.apk` while regular apps - `data/app/<app_package>/<app_name>.apk`

Comment: If I move my apk to system/app/<app_name>/<app_name>.apk path by app become system app or I should also need to sign apk using those .pk8  and .pem files?

Comment: don't know about that, but you have to move it there for sure. I think you will have to try by yourself

Comment: Any idea how to disable force stopping an system signed app?

Comment: I'm not sure that it should be possible.